# React Native run function any outher screen

Tags: function, react-native, screen

I have a simple question.
I want to run the function I created in App.js in a different screen.
Each screen is connected to an AppContainer in context.
I'm going to use state on another screen, but I do not know how to do it.
Can you give me a simple example?

```js
  _setDefaultLocation = locationKey => {
    console.log("call _setDefaultLocation function");
    
    this.setState({ defaultLocation: locationKey });

    console.log(this.state.defaultLocation);

    this._getCurrent(locationKey);
  };
```

The above function is called this.props._setDefaultLocation (); I tried to do this and it did not work.

```js
import React from "react";

const WeatherContext = React.createContext();

function withWeather(WrappedComponent) {
  return function withContext(props) {
    return (
      <WeatherContext.Consumer>
        {value => <WrappedComponent value={value} {...props} />}
      </WeatherContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
}

export { WeatherContext, withWeather };
```

Context is used to make it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global keyword to make your function global. Then you can use it in any screen.

For example, assume that you have a function is called 'myFunction'. You can implement your function in App.js as following.

```
global.myFunction = () => {
    console.warn('I am a global function...')
    // your function body
};
```

Then you can call this function in any screen just like other function calling..

In your case your function can implement in this format.

```
global._myFunction = locationKey => {
    console.warn('I am a global function...')
    // your function body
};
```

And when you are calling the function call it as `_myFunction(locationKey)`.

NOTE: 'locationKey' is the parameter that you should pass for your function.

Think this solution will help you.

Comment: I got syntax Error global.
global._setDefaultLocation = locationKey => {
    console.log("call _setDefaultLocation function");

    this.setState({ defaultLocation: locationKey });

    console.log(this.state.defaultLocation);

    this._getCurrent(locationKey);
  };

Comment: Is the error occur from function or else is it occurring when the function is calling?

Comment: How did you call the function

Comment: No yet call function. I just type global and save.

Comment: YES of course. 
Check App.js and line of 560.
https://github.com/charian/WhatTheWeather/blob/master/App.js#L560

Comment: Place that function after line number 1021 and try to do the same thing. See whether will it be ok